# Pattern match with stored variable or regular expression in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, variables, pattern-matching

Since I'm a biologist and do my informatics by patching and editing code form forums like this, I apologise in advance for rookie mistakes.

I've been trying to iterate over files and search pattern in File2, when this pattern is first line in File1. My goal is to append one line after pattern into outFile.

My first attempt was to insert regular expression like this:

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/"${head -1 "$File1"}"/{c=1}' "$File2" >> outFile
```

And second to store pattern into variable:

```
pattern=$(head -1 "$File1")
awk 'c&&!--c;/"$pattern"/{c=1}' "$File2" >> outFile
```

(File1 and File2 are marked with "$" because I call them with for loop.)

But neither works. If I directly write pattern it works OK, so everything else seems to be fine.

So I'm dealing with sequence data, and after blasting I get list of hits into File1 which looks something like this:

```
BLAST_hit_Jerry
BLAST_hit_Tom
BLAST_hit_Dog
...
```

Now Jerry is the best. I would like to extract first line (BLAST hit Jerry) and pattern match it in sequence file (File2), that looks like:

```
>BLAST_hit_BugsBunny_andsomethingelse
unique_sequence_BugsBunny
>BLAST_hit_MickyMouse_andsomethingelse
unique_sequence_MickyMouse
>BLAST_hit_Jerry_andsomethingelse
unique_sequence_Jerry
...
```

I have many File1 BLAST hit files and corresponding File2 sequence files that I iterate over and always store into outFile only one unique_sequence that corresponds to top BLAST hit. outFile would look something like:

```
unique_sequence_Jerry
unique_sequence_from_second_loop_(other sequence corresponding to next top BLAST hit)
unique_sequence ...
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Is it a regex pattern or a fixed string that you're trying to match?

Comment: I'm trying to match regex, that returns string (first line in File1). I just validated  with fixed string that the rest of  the code is working fine.

Comment: In folder I have multiple File1 - File2 pairs that I iterate over and store output into single outFile.

Comment: Thanks for adding your sample input but its relation to the output isn't exactly clear. Could you show the _exact_ output for a specific input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$pattern` isn't expanded inside the single quotes. Pass the value as an `awk` variable, then use the `~` operator to match the value.

```
awk -v p="$pattern" 'c&&!--c; $0 ~ p {c=1}' "$File2" >> outFile
```